# Length of fields in an RSA CRT Key

Tags: rsa, keys

In a 2048 bit RSA key. Are $P, Q$, exponent $P$, exponent $Q$, and the coefficient guaranteed to be half of the length of the modulus (128 bytes)?

Comment: Yes, the length of the primes is half that of the modulus. What do you mean by "the coefficient"?

Comment: qinv. The crypto library I use refers to it as coefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it is not guaranteed that in a 2048-bit RSA key, the prime factors $p$ and $q$ of the modulus are exactly half of the length of the modulus or 128 octets; much less so for $d_p$, $d_q$, and $q_\text{inv}$ .

In particular, [PKCS#1v2.2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=7) allows almost total freedom on size of $p$ and $q$ (and even allows more than two prime factors for the public modulus). $p$ and $q$ being of exactly equal size however follows from requirements mandated by some common standards, in particular [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=51), which requires $p$ and $q$ to be in the interval $(2^{1023.5},2^{1024})$ for a 2048-bit modulus.  This can be traced to its ancestor on RSA matters, ANSI X9.31 (1998).

While having $p$ and $q$ of exactly half the modulus is definitely common, there are implementations around which generate $p$ and $q$ of different size, and even standards like [ETSI TS 102 176-1](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102100_102199/10217601/02.01.01_60/ts_10217601v020101p.pdf#page=18) with recommendation that clearly allow that, and have been interpreted as favoring it:

> $p$ and $q$ should have roughly the same length, e.g. set a range such as $0,1 < | \log_2p - \log_2q | < 30$;

---

Even if $p$ and $q$ are exactly 1024-bit, this does not insure that $d_p$, $d_q$, and $q_\text{inv}$ are *exactly* 1024-bit or 128-octet. They are often slightly smaller: the high order bits of $q_\text{inv}$ behave about as if $q_\text{inv}$ was random in interval $(0,p)$, thus $q_\text{inv}<2^{1016}$ with probability I guess at least $1/256$ (I welcome a proof or refutation of the estimate, or/and a better one).